# google apps scripts: returning multiple objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Using the function `load_table()` below, I'm loading the content of a google doc spreadsheet into a hash variable `tbl`. Using the helper function `test_hash()` I can see that `tbl` is visible within `load_table()`, along with `bt` , `cod` and `st` which also contain data from the spreadsheet (`cod` is a constant). Everything is as expected.

When I try to return all these variables by putting them into another hash variable `res`, I loose `tbl`: for some reason `tbl` is blank while the other variables are there as expected. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

```
function load_table( ss_data , colPos ) {

  // create hash from ss_data
  // ========================

  var bt  = [];
  var st  = [];
  var tbl = [];
  var cod = '';

  for (var i = 1; i < ss_data.length; i++) {
    cod = ss_data[i][0]
    bt[ ss_data[i][1] ] = 1;
    st[ ss_data[i][2] ] = 1;
    tbl[ ss_data[i][1] + '~' + ss_data[i][2] ] = ss_data[i][colPos];
  }

  test_hash(tbl);

  var btLvls = Object.keys(bt).sort();
  var stLvls = Object.keys(st).sort();

  var res = {};
  res['cod'] = cod;
  res['bt'] = btLvls;
  res['st'] = stLvls;
  res['tbl'] = tbl;

  test_hash(tbl);
  test_hash(res);

  return res;
 }
```

`test_hash()` is a simple debug function:

```
 function test_hash( h ) {
  Logger.log( " --------- HASH START -------- " );
  for ( var index in h ){
     Logger.log( index + ':' +  h[index] )
  }
  Logger.log( " --------- HASH END -------- " );
 }
```

This is the corresponding `doGet()` function:

```
function doGet(){
  // counts by yearmo

  var liveid = 'xxxxx'
  var testid = 'yyyyy'

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( testid );

  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  var rencat_nbtids = load_table( data , 3 );
  var rencat_nstids = load_table( data , 4 );
  var rencat_nsubs  = load_table( data , 5 );

  Logger.log( rencat_nbtids );

}
```

Comment: This question would be improved with the addition of sample data - an example `test()` function with valid canned data would be helpful. If you'd rather provide a public sheet, great. But in the current state, this otherwise well-written question turns into a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Objects are Maps, Arrays are Lists](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Javascript_Object_and_Array.html#objects-are-maps-arrays) and [The Associative Array](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html), the problem is that `tbl` is actually an associative array aka map (Object) but you've declared it as a list (Array).

This little change in line 8 lets `tbl` survive the `return`:

```
var tbl = {};
```

[image: Screen Shot - debugger]

PS: Did you mean to start from 1 in line 11? `for (var i = 1; ...`  Arrays start at 0.